# Resource for Stochastic Calculus and Ito processes

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation

May someone please recommend a book or website where one can learn Stochastic Calculus and Ito processes from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean by "from scratch"?  Do you already know measure theory?  Functional analysis?  Basic real analysis?  Elementary probability?

Comment: Yes Nate, I already know most of those concepts. It is just stochastic calculus confuses me sometimes. and I figured maybe if i start/ learn it from first principles it will start making more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brownian Motion Calculus by Ubbo Wiersema, 
An Introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations by Lawrence Evans, 
Stochastic Differential Equations by Bernt Oksendal (not light reading, by any means)

Comment: Actually I think Øksendal has a reputation as being one of the gentler introductions to the subject (while still being mathematically rigorous).

Comment: I will look at these books. Thanks guys