# Stochastic calculus literature

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation

Could you recommend some stochastic calculus literature that has a lot of examples? I am particularly interested if there are good books with stochastic differential equations explained on real problems, for instance, some kind of a seminar-like problems-with-solutions set.

Comment: these are similar-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412942/what-is-a-good-book-for-learning-stochastic-calculus?rq=1 , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781384/resource-for-stochastic-calculus-and-ito-processes?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316164/stochastic-calculus-book-recommendation?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

The book by René Schilling & Lothar Partzsch, *Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* contains several chapters on stochastic calculus. Moreover, there are full solutions to all exercises on the [web](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/), so there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

The books by **Berndt Øksendal**, particularly *Stochastic Differential Equations, Stochastic Partial Differential Equations* and *Numerical Solutions to SPDEs* are great for beginners. The books by **Gieuseppe Da Prato, Jerzy Zabzyk, Nikolai Petrov** et.al. are great for a second reading or for seminar type material. In addition, the notes of Fields Medalist **Martin Hairer** on *The Theory of Rough Paths* is great for research material. Again, books by Abel Prize Laureate **S R S Varadhan** is also great for some related material.

Comment: I agree with you that SPDEs and rough path theory are interesting (research) topics, but I don't think that this is what the OP was looking for...

Comment: @saz But the OP asked for Stochastic Differential equations and seminar topics, which is why I thought of these.

Comment: Did you miss the "explained on real problems, for instance, some kind of a seminar-like problems-with-solutions set" part by any chance?